# How to test .then function with Jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asynchronous, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have the function below in my **react** project:

```
import domtoimage from 'dom-to-image';
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

export default async (node: HTMLElement | null, fileName: string) => {
  if (node) {
    return domtoimage.toBlob(node).then((blob) => {
      const file = new Blob([blob], { type: 'image/png' });
      saveAs(file, fileName);
    });
  }
  throw new Error('Node HTMLElement cannot be null');
};
```

It basically takes an HTML Element, transforms it into an image and downloads the image with FileSaver.

**And I did the tests below for this function:**

```
import fileSaver from 'file-saver';
import domtoimage from 'dom-to-image';
import htmlElementToImageDownload from '../domToImage';

describe('When execute domToImage function', () => {
  it('should return error if the element sent is null', async () => {
    htmlElementToImageDownload(null, 'test').then((data) => {
      expect(data).toThrowError(Error);
    });
  });

  it('should execute the function toBlob and saveAs', async () => {
    const spyGeteElementById = jest.spyOn(document, 'getElementById');
    const spyToBlob = jest.spyOn(domtoimage, 'toBlob');
    const spySaveAs = jest.spyOn(fileSaver, 'saveAs');

    const mockElement = document.createElement('div');
    spyGeteElementById.mockReturnValue(mockElement);

    htmlElementToImageDownload(mockElement, 'test').then(() => {
      expect(spyToBlob).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(spySaveAs).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    spyToBlob.mockRestore();
    spySaveAs.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

But when I check the application's test coverage, it reports that the lines below (what's inside the "then") are not being tested:

```
const file = new Blob([blob], { type: 'image/png' });
saveAs(file, fileName);
```

**What am I doing wrong in my test?**

**How can I test the "promise" snippet?**

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous, https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous#promises, and https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous#promises might be  good places to reference

Comment: @Jhecht, thank for the references, I read it and what I did is similar and it works. The problem is that the test coverage says that the snippet I reported in the question is not being tested. Why does it happen?

Comment: that I can't tell you unfortunately. Jest's coverage report to me has always been pretty finnicky. I've never looked into it.